# Styling kendo angular tabs; arrow under active tab

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, css-selectors, kendo-ui-angular2

I'd like to override the default style of the [kendo angular tabstrip](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/tabstrip/), ideally in a way that follows best practices. Right now, I'm using `::ng-deep` selectors, which I know is bad practice; but so far can't figure out a different way. Check out my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ildngw).

I'm also having trouble implementing an arrow under the active tab. In the above example, I'd like a way to achieve this:

[image]

A small white triangle/arrow that appears under the active tab. I think a pure CSS solution would be the best, but I'm open to other solutions. It needs to be in the center of the selected tab, regardless of its length. Please try to make it work in the stackblitz I provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in CSS only using the :after pseudo element on the active LI. Draw the triangle and position it:

Updated **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ildngw-y5wrqy?file=index.html)**

```
li.k-state-active:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I needed. I'd appreciate it if you had any advice on the placement of the css. Like I said, I'm using `::ng-deep` for everything, but I know that's bad practice.

Comment: @igg, I personally don't use angular, so I don't have advice about that aspect of your question. Good luck!